# Split Wav File in VB6

Tags: join, split, vb6, mp3, wav

I need help to fix the attached VB6 code which is supposed to take an audio file and split it into 5 equal parts.

This is the way this code should work:

The first part starts from the beginning of Track.wav file.
The second part starts from where the first split part ended.
The third part starts from where the second split part ended.
The fourth part starts from where the third split part ended.
The fifth part starts from where the fourth split part ended.

Essentially each of the file parts is a continuation of the previous part of file split. After the split I have 1.wav, 2.wav, 3.wav. 4.wav and 5.wav all derived from a Track.wav file. The code attached already splits the file into five equal parts but the problem is that all the audio parts are the same as the first part instead of a continuation.

I need help to get this fixed to work as it should in VB6 (not .NET). I'd be grateful for your assistance with this.

```
Dim Wavlength As Integer

Private Sub Command1_Click()

On Error Resume Next

DoFirstWav

Me.SetFocus

End Sub

Private Sub DoFirstWav()

On Error Resume Next

Dim ByteData() As Byte
Dim FirstWav As Integer

FirstWav = Wavlength / 5

ByteData = ReadFile(App.Path & "\Track.wav", 1, FirstWav & "0000")
Call WriteFile(App.Path & "\Segments\1.wav", ByteData)

DoSecondWav

End Sub

Private Sub DoSecondWav()

On Error Resume Next

Dim ByteData() As Byte
Dim SecondWav As Integer

SecondWav = Wavlength / 5

ByteData = ReadFile(App.Path & "\Track.wav", 1, SecondWav & "0000")
Call WriteFile(App.Path & "\Segments\2.wav", ByteData)

DoThirdWav

End Sub

Private Sub DoThirdWav()

On Error Resume Next

Dim ByteData() As Byte
Dim ThirdWav As Integer

ThirdWav = Wavlength / 5

ByteData = ReadFile(App.Path & "\Track.wav", 1, ThirdWav & "0000")
Call WriteFile(App.Path & "\Segments\3.wav", ByteData)

DoFourthWav

End Sub

Private Sub DoFourthWav()

On Error Resume Next

Dim ByteData() As Byte
Dim FourthWav As Integer

FourthWav = Wavlength / 5

ByteData = ReadFile(App.Path & "\Track.wav", 1, FourthWav & "0000")
Call WriteFile(App.Path & "\Segments\4.wav", ByteData)

DoFifthWav

End Sub

Private Sub DoFifthWav()

On Error Resume Next

Dim ByteData() As Byte
Dim FifthWav As Integer

FifthWav = Wavlength / 5

ByteData = ReadFile(App.Path & "\Track.wav", 1, FifthWav & "0000")
Call WriteFile(App.Path & "\Segments\5.wav", ByteData)

MsgBox "Wav Split Successfully", vbInformation

End

End Sub

Private Function ReadFile(ByVal strFileName As String, Optional ByVal lngStartPos As Long = 1, Optional ByVal lngFileSize As Long = -1) As Byte()

On Error Resume Next

Dim FilNum As Integer

FilNum = FreeFile

Open strFileName For Binary As #FilNum
    If lngFileSize = -1 Then
        ReDim ReadFile(LOF(FilNum) - lngStartPos)
        Else
        ReDim ReadFile(lngFileSize - 1)
    End If
    Get #FilNum, lngStartPos, ReadFile
Close #FilNum

End Function

Private Function WriteFile(ByVal strFileName As String, ByteData() As Byte, Optional ByVal lngStartPos As Long = -1, Optional ByVal OverWrite As Boolean = True)

On Error Resume Next

Dim FilNum As Integer

FilNum = FreeFile

If OverWrite = True And Dir(strFileName) <> "" Then
    Kill strFileName
End If

Open strFileName For Binary As #FilNum
    If lngStartPos = -1 Then
        Put #FilNum, LOF(FilNum) + 1, ByteData
        Else
        Put #FilNum, l, ByteData
    End If
Close #FilNum

End Function

Private Sub Form_Load()

On Error Resume Next

Dim MyInt As Integer
Dim MyByte As Byte
Dim MyStr As String * 4
Dim MyLong As Long
Dim SampleRate, BytesPerSample, FileSize As Long

Open App.Path & "\Track.wav" For Binary Access Read Lock Read As #1
    Get #1, , MyStr:    Debug.Print "Riff = "; MyStr
    Get #1, , MyLong:   Debug.Print "File size = "; MyLong
    FileSize = MyLong
    Get #1, , MyStr:    Debug.Print "Wave = "; MyStr
    Get #1, , MyStr:    Debug.Print "Format = "; MyStr
    Get #1, , MyLong:   Debug.Print "Any = "; MyLong
    Get #1, , MyInt:    Debug.Print "formatTag = "; MyInt
    Get #1, , MyInt:    Debug.Print "Channels = "; MyInt
    Get #1, , MyLong:   Debug.Print "Samples per Sec = "; MyLong
    SampleRate = MyLong
    Get #1, , MyInt:    Debug.Print "Bytes per Sec = "; MyInt
    Get #1, , MyInt:    Debug.Print "BlockAlign = "; MyInt
    Get #1, , MyInt:    Debug.Print "Bytes per Sample = "; MyInt
    BytesPerSample = MyInt
Close #1

Wavlength = FileSize / (SampleRate * BytesPerSample)

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you not always starting at position 1 on your ReadFile calls?

Comment: Hello Brian, thanks for reply. I don't know how this code is done. I did not do this code. So I can't answer your question. Please help if you can to get it working as it should. This is part of a school project and am not sure where problem is.

Comment: Look at the lines where you read the file.  You always start at 1.  That's why all 5 files are the same.   So change these lines so you start at the right spot.

Comment: Hi Brian, so what should I change the 1 to? I’m not sure what you are saying. Please can you give an example? I’ve incremental each sub by changing from the first to 1, then 2, then 3, 4, 5 but nothing changed. I’m sure I’m not doing the correct changes. Perhaps, you can just show me. Thanks

Comment: You want to split your file into 5 equal pieces.  Each piece is therefore 20% of the file size.  So if the file is 10 bytes each piece is 2 bytes.  Starting at 1 for the first piece, the second piece starts at 3, the third piece starts at 5, then 7 then 9.  Do this same idea with your code.

Comment: In calculation of the length of your blocks, don´t forget to write also a file header for each block for your wave files. If you do not, the files may be unusable.

Comment: @BrianMStafford 

I have done as you suggested but unfortunately that does not make any difference. Thanks

Comment: Do all 5 files need to be playable?  If so, you also need to create header records for each file as noted above.

Comment: Yes, they do. I am supposed to split original file into 5 segments for continuous play. Each part starts from where previous one stops.

Comment: I have no idea how to do this in the first place. It's why I have asked for help. If I did, I'd have done it since. I'm just learning this stuff and I get more confused trying to do what I don't know in the first place without an example or guide with posted code to show me what to do. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Keno I'll work on an example and post it soon.

Comment: @BrianMStafford  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite involved, particularly if each part needs to be playable.  The reason is that each file you create needs to have a valid header record.  To complicate it further, it appears a header record may be 44 bytes, 46 bytes, or even other sizes.

I worked out some basic code based on your post that appears to work for the wav file I tested:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const HEADER_SIZE As Long = 46
Private Const CHUNK_COUNT As Long = 5

Private HeaderData(HEADER_SIZE) As Byte
Private ChunkSize As Long

Private Sub Form_Load()
   Dim MyInt As Integer
   Dim MyByte As Byte
   Dim MyStr As String * 4
   Dim MyLong As Long
   Dim FileSize As Long

   Open App.Path & "\Track.wav" For Binary Access Read Lock Read As #1
   Get #1, , MyStr:    Debug.Print "Riff = "; MyStr
   Get #1, , MyLong:   Debug.Print "File size = "; MyLong
   Get #1, , MyStr:    Debug.Print "Wave = "; MyStr
   Get #1, , MyStr:    Debug.Print "Format = "; MyStr
   Get #1, , MyLong:   Debug.Print "Any = "; MyLong
   Get #1, , MyInt:    Debug.Print "formatTag = "; MyInt
   Get #1, , MyInt:    Debug.Print "Channels = "; MyInt
   Get #1, , MyLong:   Debug.Print "Samples per Sec = "; MyLong
   Get #1, , MyInt:    Debug.Print "Bytes per Sec = "; MyInt
   Get #1, , MyInt:    Debug.Print "BlockAlign = "; MyInt
   Get #1, , MyInt:    Debug.Print "Bytes per Sample = "; MyInt
   Get #1, , MyInt:    Debug.Print "Something = "; MyInt  'for my wave file, I needed 2 extra bytes
   Get #1, , MyStr:    Debug.Print "SubchunkID = "; MyStr
   Get #1, , FileSize: Debug.Print "SubchunkSize = "; FileSize
   Get #1, 1, HeaderData  'the size changes depending upon the file
   Close #1

   ChunkSize = CLng(FileSize / CHUNK_COUNT)  'you might loose some data here
End Sub

Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim ByteData() As Byte
   Dim StartPos As Long

   For i = 1 To CHUNK_COUNT
      StartPos = HEADER_SIZE + ((i - 1) * ChunkSize)
      ByteData = ReadFile(App.Path & "\Track.wav", StartPos, ChunkSize)
      Call WriteFile(App.Path & "\Segments\" & i & ".wav", HeaderData, ByteData)
   Next

   MsgBox "Wav Split Successfully", vbInformation
   End
End Sub

Private Function ReadFile(ByVal strFileName As String, ByVal lngStartPos As Long, ByVal lngFileSize As Long) As Byte()
   On Error Resume Next

   Dim FilNum As Integer

   FilNum = FreeFile

   ReDim ReadFile(lngFileSize - 1)

   Open strFileName For Binary As #FilNum

   Get #FilNum, lngStartPos, ReadFile

   Close #FilNum
End Function

Private Function WriteFile(ByVal strFileName As String, HeaderData() As Byte, ByteData() As Byte, Optional ByVal OverWrite As Boolean = True)
   On Error Resume Next

   Dim FilNum As Integer

   FilNum = FreeFile

   If OverWrite = True And Dir(strFileName) <> "" Then
       Kill strFileName
   End If

   Open strFileName For Binary As #FilNum

   Put #FilNum, LOF(FilNum) + 1, HeaderData
   Put #FilNum, HEADER_SIZE, ByteData

   Close #FilNum
End Function
```

I eliminated a lot of duplicate code by implementing a `For` loop.  In that loop, I calculate the Start position for the Read, and also pass the header record for the Write.

Again, I stress that this is very basic and will not work for all wav files.  You can manually adjust the HEADER_SIZE if it does not work for your file.

Likely the header record needs to be modified to reflect the correct size of the new file, instead of using the header from the original file.

This should get you started.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to put this example together. Unfortunately, that did not work. It split the wav file but they were all 0 bytes and not playable. So I reverted to old code with changes and finally got that work :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the working code. I'm sure someone may need something like this in future, si thought I'd post it here.

```
Dim Wavlength As Long
Dim PartLength As Integer
Dim WavHeader() As Byte

Private Sub Command1_Click()

On Error Resume Next

WavHeader = ReadFile(App.Path & "\Track.wav", 1, 320)

PartLength = Wavlength / 6 - 2

DoFirstWav

End Sub

Private Sub DoFirstWav()

On Error Resume Next

Dim ByteData() As Byte
Dim FirstWav As Integer

ByteData = ReadFile(App.Path & "\Track.wav", 1, PartLength & "0000")
Call WriteFile(App.Path & "\Segments\1.wav", ByteData)

DoSecondWav

End Sub

Private Sub DoSecondWav()

On Error Resume Next

Dim ByteData() As Byte
Dim ByteRead() As Byte
Dim SecondWav As Integer

SecondWav = PartLength

ByteRead = ReadFile(App.Path & "\Track.wav", SecondWav & "0000", PartLength & "0000")

ReDim ByteData(UBound(WavHeader) + UBound(ByteRead)) As Byte

For i = 0 To UBound(WavHeader)
    ByteData(i) = WavHeader(i)
Next i

For i = 0 To UBound(ByteRead)
    ByteData(UBound(WavHeader) + i) = ByteRead(i)
Next i

Call WriteFile(App.Path & "\Segments\2.wav", ByteData)

DoThirdWav

End Sub

Private Sub DoThirdWav()

On Error Resume Next

Dim ByteData() As Byte
Dim ByteRead() As Byte
Dim ThirdWav As Integer

ThirdWav = PartLength * 2 + 1

ByteRead = ReadFile(App.Path & "\Track.wav", ThirdWav & "0000", PartLength & "0000")

ReDim ByteData(UBound(WavHeader) + UBound(ByteRead)) As Byte

For i = 0 To UBound(WavHeader)
    ByteData(i) = WavHeader(i)
Next i

For i = 0 To UBound(ByteRead)
    ByteData(UBound(WavHeader) + i) = ByteRead(i)
Next i

Call WriteFile(App.Path & "\Segments\3.wav", ByteData)

DoFourthWav

End Sub

Private Sub DoFourthWav()

On Error Resume Next

Dim ByteData() As Byte
Dim ByteRead() As Byte
Dim FourthWav As Integer

FourthWav = PartLength * 3 + 1

ByteRead = ReadFile(App.Path & "\Track.wav", FourthWav & "0000", PartLength & "0000")

ReDim ByteData(UBound(WavHeader) + UBound(ByteRead)) As Byte

For i = 0 To UBound(WavHeader)
    ByteData(i) = WavHeader(i)
Next i

For i = 0 To UBound(ByteRead)
    ByteData(UBound(WavHeader) + i) = ByteRead(i)
Next i

Call WriteFile(App.Path & "\Segments\4.wav", ByteData)

DoFifthWav

End Sub

Private Sub DoFifthWav()

On Error Resume Next

Dim ByteData() As Byte
Dim ByteRead() As Byte
Dim FifthWav As Integer

FifthWav = PartLength * 4 + 1

ByteRead = ReadFile(App.Path & "\Track.wav", FifthWav & "0000", PartLength & "0000")

ReDim ByteData(UBound(WavHeader) + UBound(ByteRead)) As Byte

For i = 0 To UBound(WavHeader)
    ByteData(i) = WavHeader(i)
Next i

For i = 0 To UBound(ByteRead)
    ByteData(UBound(WavHeader) + i) = ByteRead(i)
Next i

Call WriteFile(App.Path & "\Segments\5.wav", ByteData)

End Sub

Private Function ReadFile(ByVal strFileName As String, Optional ByVal lngStartPos As Long = 1, Optional ByVal lngFileSize As Long = -1) As Byte()

On Error Resume Next

Dim FilNum As Integer

FilNum = FreeFile

Open strFileName For Binary As #FilNum
    If lngFileSize = -1 Then
        ReDim ReadFile(LOF(FilNum) - lngStartPos)
        Else
        ReDim ReadFile(lngFileSize - 1)
    End If
    Get #FilNum, lngStartPos, ReadFile
Close #FilNum

End Function

Private Function WriteFile(ByVal strFileName As String, ByteData() As Byte, Optional ByVal lngStartPos As Long = -1, Optional ByVal OverWrite As Boolean = True)

On Error Resume Next

Dim FilNum As Integer

FilNum = FreeFile

If OverWrite = True And Dir(strFileName) <> "" Then
    Kill strFileName
End If

Open strFileName For Binary As #FilNum
    If lngStartPos = -1 Then
        Put #FilNum, LOF(FilNum) + 1, ByteData
        Else
        Put #FilNum, l, ByteData
    End If
Close #FilNum

End Function

Private Sub Form_Load()

On Error Resume Next

Dim MyInt As Integer
Dim MyByte As Byte
Dim MyStr As String * 4
Dim MyLong As Long
Dim SampleRate, BytesPerSample, FileSize As Long

Open App.Path & "\Track.wav" For Binary Access Read Lock Read As #1
    Get #1, , MyStr:    Debug.Print "Riff = "; MyStr
    Get #1, , MyLong:   Debug.Print "File size = "; MyLong
    FileSize = MyLong
    Get #1, , MyStr:    Debug.Print "Wave = "; MyStr
    Get #1, , MyStr:    Debug.Print "Format = "; MyStr
    Get #1, , MyLong:   Debug.Print "Any = "; MyLong
    Get #1, , MyInt:    Debug.Print "formatTag = "; MyInt
    Get #1, , MyInt:    Debug.Print "Channels = "; MyInt
    Get #1, , MyLong:   Debug.Print "Samples per Sec = "; MyLong
    SampleRate = MyLong
    Get #1, , MyInt:    Debug.Print "Bytes per Sec = "; MyInt
    Get #1, , MyInt:    Debug.Print "BlockAlign = "; MyInt
    Get #1, , MyInt:    Debug.Print "Bytes per Sample = "; MyInt
    BytesPerSample = MyInt

Close #1

Wavlength = FileSize \ (SampleRate * BytesPerSample)

Debug.Print "Wavlength"; Wavlength

End Sub
```